# how do I create react js pattern for the following API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following API of the user's post list

```
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "url": "http://blablabla/api/v1/postdetail/24"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "url": "http://blablabla/api/v1/postdetail/23"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "url": "http://blablabla/api/v1/postdetail/22"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "url": "http://blablabla/api/v1/postdetail/21"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "url": "http://blablabla/api/v1/postdetail/20"
    },
]
```

I have tried of making PostList.js
this file has useEffect that fetches Post List API (resulting to the API above)
and inside it's JSX has this kind of code example below

**PostList.js**

```
function PostList(props) {
  const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.posts_api);
    axios
      .get(`${props.posts_api}`, {
        headers: header_in_request,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPostList(res.data);

        console.log('not errorz');
        console.log(res.data);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {error == '' ? (
        postList.length > 0 ? (
          postList.map(function (post) {
            return (
              // the line where that error had pointed to . after it tried to mount the PostCoba component
              <Post key={post.id} post_api={post.url} />
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h2>this user has not posted anything yet</h2>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h2>{error}</h2>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

the Post.js is a file that fetches the url props that was passed in.
and displays it's Post data

**Post.js**

```
function Post(props) {
  const [postDetail, setPostDetail] = useState({
    id: '',
    poster: {},
    postphoto_set: [],
  });

  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${props.post_api}`, {
        headers: header_in_request,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPostDetail(res.data);

        console.log('not errorz');
        console.log(res.data);
        setError('');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {console.log('jsx is running')}
      {error == '' ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          {postDetail.id !== '' ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className="media border p-3" key={postDetail.id}>
                <img
                  src="img_avatar3.png"
                  alt="John Doe"
                  className="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle"
                  style={{ width: '60px' }}
                />
                <div className="media-body">
                  <h4>
                    {' '}
                    {postDetail.poster.name}
                    <small>
                      <i>{postDetail.created_at}</i>
                    </small>
                  </h4>
                  <h2>{postDetail.title}</h2>
                  <pre>{postDetail.text}</pre>
                  <p>&#9733; {postDetail.likes_amount} likes</p>

                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                      {postDetail.likebutton == true ? (
                        <input
                          type="image"
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/icons/like-blue.png`}
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <input
                          type="image"
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/icons/like-black.png`}
                        />
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                      <button type="button" className="btn">
                        Comment
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                      <button type="button" className="btn">
                        Share
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                {
                  // showcomment == true && (
                  //        <CommentList
                  //            comments_api = {post.comments}
                  //        />
                  //    )
                }
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment>
              <h2>loading..</h2>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <h2>{error}</h2>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

but I had this error (see the commented code in PostList.js above to knowing the error line)
it says

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function

is there any better code pattern of how to display the each of the post API inside the PostList API ?
or is there any way to fix the error ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

It took me a while to spot your mistake. Effectively, it all boils down to the fact that, in JS, `'' != null`.

Your `PostList.js` component starts off with the `error` state set to the empty string. Then, in your `useEffect()` callback that runs when the component mounts, you make an asynchronous call that succeeds and sets the posts array state, which mounts an array of the `Post.js` components.

So far, so good. But now things start to go wrong.

When the `Post` component mounts, it has its own "on mount" `useEffect()` async call, which doesn't have time to return before...

...execution resumes in the `PostList` success callback for the API call. This then **sets the error state to `null`**. This causes React to schedule a re-render of the `PostList` component. It does not run the effect again, but when it gets to `error == ''` in the rendering logic, that is evaluated to be `false` and execution jumps to the else clause of the ternary operator, which renders an error of `null`. This also **unmounts the complete array of `Post` components**.

Shortly afterward, the API calls made by the (now-unmounted) `Post` components return, and their success callbacks are run, which includes a `setPostDetail()` call. But because those components are unmounted, the warning you are seeing is logged.

#### The solution

The immediate solution is to ensure that you are calling `setError('')` not `setError(null)`. But that doesn't solve the real problem here, which is the lack of cancellation of in-flight API requests when your components get unmounted.

To do this, use an [axios `CancelToken`](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), which you can then use to cancel the request (if it hasn't already completed) when the component unmounts.

e.g.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.posts_api);
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();

    
    axios
      .get(`${props.posts_api}`, {
        headers: header_in_request,
        cancelToken: source.token,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPostList(res.data);

        console.log('not errorz');
        console.log(res.data);
        setError('');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
      });
     
      // the important bit: returning a way for React to cancel the request.
      return () => source.cancel();
  }, []);
```

#### Further Reading

See the React docs for ["Effects with cleanup"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) for more on why you should always return a cleanup function from effect functions that do anything asynchronously.